# Is the jacobian determinant part of the probability density function?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions

Consider a PDF (Probability Density Function) $f(x,y)$ such that

$\iint_A f(x,y) \text{d}x\text{d}y$ = 1

If I express a similar integral in polar coordinates

$\iint_A f(r,\theta) r \text{d}r\text{d}\theta$ = 1

Then should I interpret
$f(r,\theta)$ as a PDF
or
$f(r,\theta)\cdot r$

Or in other words, should I include the determinant of the Jacobian in my definition of the PDF in polar coordinates (or any coordinate system)?

Comment: I don't know what a PDF is, but your set $A$ has to change if you do a coordinate transformation.

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek I edited my answer. Do I need to change the set A  even if the integration is over the same area?

Comment: You don't have to, but it will have strange results sometimes. For example sets like $[-10,10]\times [-10,10]$ don't really make sense in polar coordinates.
Additionally, if you don't change the set there is no real connection between the integrals, even if the set does make sense in both coordinates. Especially you cannot expect them to be equal without any additional assumptions.

Comment: The pdf of $(R, \Theta)$ is given by $r f(r, \theta)$, since this is the function that integrates to $1$. More info here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Dependent_variables_and_change_of_variables Regarding the set $A$, in the second integral, it should be the transformation of the set in the first integral e.g. $\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2 + y^2 < 1\}$ can be transformed to the set $\{(r, \theta) \in [0, \infty) \times [0, 2\pi) : r < 1\}$.

Comment: @Alex. Thank you for pointing out that section in the wiki page. I should have read it better as is provided me with the answer. Should I delete the question?

Comment: @tgoossens no problem. Personally I don't think you should delete the question - someone else might have the same question and find the wiki page and our answers to be helpful.